# How to negate the following regex?

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex:

```
\([^)]+\d{4}\)
```

to match scientific citations (they are between parentheses and end with a year):

```
Text text text (Hung et al., 2020; Sung et al., 2021) text text
```

Now I want to match everything that is not a scientific citation (in this case, `Text text text` and `text text`). I tried using a negative lookahead:

```
(?!\([^)]+\d{4}\))
```

But when I tried to replace the matches with nothing, nothing was replaced.

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ck2Fce/3)

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to match? `Text text text` and `text text`?

Comment: You could simply split the string on the bits that match your regex. For example, in Ruby, if the variable `str` holds the string in your example, `str.split(/\([^)]+\d{4}\/) #=> ["Text text text ", " text text")`. To also remove unwanted preceding and trailing spaces, `str.split(/\([^)]+\d{4}\/).map(&:strip) #=> ["Text text text", "text text")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the regex flavor, you could use either a capture group:

```
\([^)]+\d{4}\)|(\S.*?)(?=\s*(?:\([^)]+\d{4}\)|$))
```

**Explanation**

- `\([^)]+\d{4}\)` Match the scientific pattern
- `|` or
- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 1**, start with a non whitespace char and match 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*(?:\([^)]+\d{4}\)|$))` Positive lookahead, assert either the scientific pattern directly to the right, or the end of the string followed by optional whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LSnJLo/1)

Or with pcre using a SKIP FAIL approach:

```
\([^)]+\d{4}\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S.*?(?=\s*(?:\([^)]+\d{4}\)|$))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fxMBRN/1)

Comment: I heard your wings flapping and suspected you might be landing here.

Answer (score 2):

PCRE2:

```
\([^)]+\d{4}\)         # Match a scientific citation
|                      # or
(?<=^|\s)              # something preceded by the beginning of the line or a whitespace
(?:                    # that consists of
  .(?!\([^)]+\d{4}\))  #             characters not followed by a scientific citation.
)+                     # one or more
```

This solution captures both wanted and unwanted results, therefore you'll need to filter them using a programming language. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23589204) for an explanation on the technique.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Ck2Fce/6).

Comment: Match and capture what you want, only match want you don't want, then in code extract captures (an established technique, not something I just invented).

Comment: Correct, but that requires another pair of parentheses, which further, and unnecessarily, complicates the answer. I'll add a link to an excellent answer on that matter.